# Propagator in $\phi^3$ Theory in $d=0$ Spacetime Dimensions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, propagator

I am working through some problems in Srednicki's book in QFT (page 70).  In one of the problems we work with the following integral:

$$Z[g,J]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx \; \exp \bigg[-\frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{6}gx^3 + Jx \bigg].$$

The solution to the problem uses the fact that this is really the path integral of $\phi^3$ theory in $d=0$ spacetime dimensions, hence in its Feynman-diagram expansion each propagator is of the form

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx \; e^{-x^2/2}x^2.$$

Could someone explain why this is the propagator in this case?  (Apologies if this is trivial as I have not been studying QFT for long).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partition function $Z[J]$ is the generating function of correlation functions:

$$
\frac{\delta^{n} Z[J]}{\delta J (x_1) ... \delta J (x_n)}\biggl\vert_{J=0}
=
\langle \phi(x_1) \ldots \phi(x_n) \rangle,
$$

which also means

$$
Z[J] = 1 + \int dx \langle \phi(x) \rangle J(x) 
+\int dx dy \, \langle \phi(x) \phi(y) \rangle J(x) J(y) + \ldots.
$$

In particular the propagator is defined as the two-point correlation
of the free theory:

$$
\Delta (x_1 - x_2) := \langle \phi(x_1) \phi(x_2) \rangle 
= \frac{\delta^{2} Z_{0}[J]}{\delta J(x_1) \delta J(x_2)}\biggl\vert_{J=0}.
$$

In your case, considering

$$
Z[J,g=0] = Z_{0} [J] = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx \; \exp \bigg[\frac{1}{2}x^2 + Jx \bigg],
$$

we get

$$
\Delta (x_1 - x_2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx \; x^2 \exp \bigg(\frac{1}{2}x^2 \bigg).
$$

Let me finish with a small comment: A free theory is given by the quadratic part of the action. The definition of propagator that I gave fits nicely into Feynman's diagrammatic approach because $Z_0$ corresponds to the zeroth order expansion in the coupling constant $g$.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask something else, in a following exercise we are asked to show that the interaction picture field obeys the Klein-Gordon equation.  In the solutions it says this can be shown by writing the time derivatives as commutators with $H_0$ and work them out directly.  I'm not sure what they mean by this, is this something to do with the fact that an operator commutes with its derivatives?

Comment: No I don't mind. Ask whatever you want. But it might be best to ask another question on the site. More people will be able to help you. For this specific case, it seems that they are using Heisenberg equations of motion.

Comment: So $Z[J]$ is the partition function but it's also the path integral for the field theory?

Comment: Yes. If you are confused about this, I suggest trying to prove it yourself. I basically outlined the proof, just use the path integral expression for $\langle \phi_{1} \ldots \phi_{n} \rangle$ and rearrange everything in terms of a exponential.

Comment: Right, this is starting to make a bit more sense now.  So $Z_0$ is the zero-order term in a perturbation expansion and corresponds to the path integral for free field theory, then $Z[J]$ for an interacting field theory can be written as proportional to $Z_0$ and exponential of integral of $L_1$.  $Z_1$ corresponds to expansion in orders of $g$ and $J$ besides zero-order, is that right?

Comment: ie. we are using the interaction picture in a sense, since we have $Z_0$ for the evolution of the field operators in terms of free fields and then interactions are contained in $Z_1$ which can be treated as a perturbation series, with the Feynman diagrams being used to organize identical terms for various orders of the coupling constant in the perturbation.

Comment: The notation $Z_{1}$ is not standard, and I am not that familiar with Srednicki. But you seem to get the picture now. As long as I could follow what you were saying, it sounded reasonable.